# Display SSAS Data in ASP.NET GridView issue

Tags: asp.net

I have developed a ASP.Net web application using adomd to display the ssas cube data.

I am able to bind the data into gridview but the problem is i am unable to display the header name in the gridview. I read through the below article too but no luck. does anyknow how to fix it.

```
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28290/Microsoft-Analysis-Services-2005-Displaying-a-grid
```

thanks

Comment: Use `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false` in the gridview markup, and manually define the column definitions inside `<Columns>`

Comment: @mshsayem..thanks for your response.i know that will work.. but the trick here is i am using girdview is for dynamic result...** i.e i will chose the fields from treeview whatever i want  and display them .** so i cannot hard code the columns

Answer (score 0):

Use `RowDataBound` event of gridview. Then in the event handler check for header row and set appropriate header in appropriate cells. For example, say we have this gridview markup:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ID="gv" OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound"></asp:GridView>
```

and, on page load we are binding data like:

```
var myData = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i => new { Value = i.ToString() });
gv.DataSource = myData;
gv.DataBind();
```

and in the rowdatabound event handler we can do this to change the header:

```
protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "My Custom Header";
    }
}
```